# BITMAPV5HEADER Size?

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to use BITMAPV5HEADER with CreateDIBSection to get a uint8[] in form of RGBA. I am doing this from ctypes but this isn't a ctypes question but I'll post the code so you can see it. The ctypes guys won't know whats up here it's a winapi thing.

I double checked my struct, function, and type declares but I keep getting GetLastError of 87 which is invalid parameter after calling `CreateDIBSection`. If I set the bv5Size to the size of `BITMAPINFOHEADER` which is `40` it works but is treated as BITMAPINFO header and the red,blue,green,alpha masks dont affect it, as I still get BGRA.

#### So I was wondering what is the size supposed to be for BITMAPV5HEADER on 32bit and 64bit please. For me I'm getting 124:

```
"ostypes.TYPE.BITMAPINFOHEADER.size:" 40
"ostypes.TYPE.BITMAPV5HEADER.size:" 124
```

This is my ctypes code just to show that everything is correct:

```
            var bmi = ostypes.TYPE.BITMAPV5HEADER();
            bmi.bV5Size = ostypes.TYPE.BITMAPV5HEADER.size;
            bmi.bV5Width = nWidth; //w;
            bmi.bV5Height = -1 * nHeight; //-1 * h; // top-down
            bmi.bV5Planes = 1;
            bmi.bV5BitCount = nBPP; //32;
            bmi.bV5Compression = ostypes.CONST.BI_BITFIELDS;
            bmi.bV5RedMask   =  ostypes.TYPE.DWORD('0x00FF0000');
            bmi.bV5GreenMask =  ostypes.TYPE.DWORD('0x0000FF00');
            bmi.bV5BlueMask  =  ostypes.TYPE.DWORD('0x000000FF');
            bmi.bV5AlphaMask =  ostypes.TYPE.DWORD('0xFF000000'); // 0x00000000 for opaque, otherwise 0xff000000

            var cBmi = ctypes.cast(bmi.address(), ostypes.TYPE.BITMAPINFO.ptr); // cBmi is now a pointer so no need to pass cBmi.address() to CreateDIBSection

            var pixelBuffer = ostypes.TYPE.BYTE.ptr();
            var hbmp = ostypes.API('CreateDIBSection')(hdcMemoryDC, cBmi, ostypes.CONST.DIB_RGB_COLORS, pixelBuffer.address(), null, 0);
```

This is ctypes so I don't have to memset bmi after creation as by default it is initialized memset 0.

Thanks

Comment: It's working for me. Size is 124 too. What is your value for BI_BITFIELDS ? It should be 3.

Comment: Ah hi agian @ElderBug haha, that's so weird. I also am using 3 I can't figure out why on earth its giving me that haha. I even tricked the function declare to be BITMAPV5HEADER so i dont have to cast to BITMAPINFO and it still gives me invalid param (87) Ill examin this some more. This is me setting it: https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/digitanks-method/modules/workers/MainWorker.js#L158 and this is my declares: https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/digitanks-method/modules/ostypes_win.jsm#L151

Comment: Your nBPP is 12 instead of 32. BITSPIXEL should be 32.

Comment: Oh no way @ElderBug how did you find that out? Let me test again i thought i could swear it was 32

Comment: My bad, I can't know its value, check that nBPP is 32 to be sure.

Comment: Hmm @ElderBug I use set `BITSPIXEL` constant to 32 then do `var nBPP = ostypes.API('GetDeviceCaps')(hdcScreen, ostypes.CONST.BITSPIXEL)` it is giving me `255` is tha tright?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77071/discussion-between-elderbug-and-noitidart).

Comment: If you want to know the size and layout of a struct, compile a simple C++ program and let the compiler give you the definitive answer.